# two keys are same hashMap over write" the existing one?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

How exactly hash map store data internally ... I knew it will calculate HashCode value of key and store it.If two key having same hash code it will put into same bucket. But why if "two keys are same hashMap over write" the existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashcode code main purpose is to reduce the number of invocation of equals method in the hash based collection. Same hash code need not return true for equals method. But if you say its equals is true, then it hascode should be true.

Answer (score 9):

Well, that's what it's designed to do. It's a mapping of key/value pairs, where any key is associated with 0 or 1 value. If you `put` a second value for a key, the entry for that key will be replaced.

It's not based just on the hash code though - it will test the keys for equality, too. Two keys can be unequal but have the same hash code. The important thing is that two equal keys *must* have the same hash code.

If you want to store multiple values for a single key, you should use something like Guava's [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Answer (score 4):

It will not overwrite the value if the `hashCode()` is same. It will overwrite only if they are equal by the [equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

Answer (score 3):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table and http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html

A hash table or hash map is an array of linked lists, keyed by hashcode.

Answer (score 1):

Hash functions are generallyy used for eliminating duplicate data.That is why collections type
like Hashmap not allowing to store duplicate data.
This algorithms has been used in database as well to eliminate possible duplicates while retrieval.